# How to Style Facebook Like Comment Pop Out Over Links?

Tags: html, css, fbml

Looking for a way in CSS (in the child theme) to make a pop out from one div display over another, without blocking the links in the lower div when the pop-out is closed.

I am trying to use the Facebook Like Button with the comment pop-out on the pages of my site and have made the .widget-pad area of my section appropriately sized to display it when it pops up, so that it goes over another section and div that is containing a large image that links to another page.

[image]

However, when the Like button is unclicked and the pop-up is not displayed the linked area (silver part in this pick) is not-clickable.

[image]

The area below where the transparant div from the Like Button is still clickable.

How to make it so I can still click the links below where a popout happens on my page?

Comment: Thank you for adding the images Cody!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer -- I needed to use CSS to select the `.widget` element and not the `.widget-pad` element I had been using before.

Note to all trying to deal with implementing Facebook Like in WordPress widget, something like this can help if you are having trouble getting the Comments pop-out to display over other `<div>`'s:

`.widget{overflow: visible}`